# Get page number and page total (eg. Page 1 of 4) into the footer of a google sheet when exporting as PDF

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Drive Sheets you can use the custom header and footer tool to add custom headers and footers when you export a spreadsheet as a PDF.

I would really like to get into the footer a statement like this :

- (psuedo code) `Page - $PageNumber of $PageCount`

which would output something like :

- "Page 1 of 4".

Im aware that you can get a Page Number in there, but is there anyway i can do the above ?

[image]

Comment: @Tedinoz could you show me where in that page is the answer to my question, i can see there is a section on custom footers, but nothing specifically on page numbers (unless if ive missed it)

Comment: You are right - there is nothing on that page that will yield the page count. I was wrong and I apologise unreservedly. Google Docs will yield Page X of Y, but it seems that Google Sheets does not have the same ability. I also apologise for suggesting that you could have established this by a quick-and-dirty google - I was wrong.

Comment: @Tedinoz no problem, if you have downvoted the question, could you upvote it please